# How to execute commands like LS,CD using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have gone through google but I didn't find anything like how to execute sftp commands using Apache camel could any one refer the example or some link relevant
to the example. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your use-case, can you explain more what and why you want to do

Comment: I want to go to particular path on Linux server and I want to check the size of the files in that folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camel-ftp component (and all the other Camel components) are intended for exchanging data (messages) between systems. They are not really intended for a Java client library with a free API you can do all sorts of thing with.

So if you want to do some special things on the FTP server then maybe use the Java FTP client API directly, and not the camel-ftp component.

That said the camel-ftp component has a download=false option you may be able to use to consume the FTP files metadata (name, size etc). But again the consumer is intended for keep monitoring the FTP server and download new files. So its not a perfect fit for your use-case.